# Combine google sheet tabs into one

Tags: google-apps-script

I have used this script to capture all the data from different google sheet tabs into one main data. However, this only works for the present tabs, but does not work for tabs that are added or deleted.
Please suggest.
Trying to do an automation to get certain data from all tabs of the same format, but this should be applicable for tabs added or deleted

```
function myFunction1() {
  const destinationSheetName = "main"; // Please set the destination sheet name.
  const excludeSheetNames = [destinationSheetName, "Sheet2"]; // If you have the exclude sheets, please set the sheet name here.

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const ssId = ss.getId();
  const ranges = ss.getSheets().reduce((ar, s) => {
    const sheetName = s.getSheetName();
    if (!excludeSheetNames.includes(sheetName)) {
      ar.push(`'${sheetName}'!A2:L`);
    }
    return ar;
  }, []).join(";");
  const formula = `=QUERY({${ranges}},"select * where Col1 is not null",0)`;
  ss.getSheetByName(destinationSheetName).clearContents().getRange("A1").setFormula(formula);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can control the data you want to see by hiding the sheets you don't wish to add to the list

```
 function myFunction1() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const xcl = ["Sheet0"]
  const ranges = ss.getSheets().filter(sh => !~xcl.indexOf(sh.getName())).filter(sh => !sh.isSheetHidden())
  .map(sh => `'${sh.getName()}'!A2:L`).join(';');
  const formula = `=QUERY({${ranges}},"select * where Col1 is not null",0)`;
  Logger.log(formula)
  ss.getSheetByName('Sheet0').clearContents().getRange("A1").setFormula(formula);
}
```